# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ not converge and yet $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ does converge? Looking for an intuition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It was proven to us that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge and yet $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ does converge, I don't doubt the proof, and yet I would like to have acquired an 'intuition' to it.

What I don't understand is what exactly is the difference between $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$. My intuition leads me to believe that the reason either of them converges is because the terms that are summed are gradually decreasing until the addition of the next term is meaningless, because both:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$
And
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$$

I would appreciate it if someone could debunk this in plain terms which refer to intuition, as I do understand the formality of the proof.

Comment: The intuition is that the terms of the first (divergent) series are much bigger than of the second (convergent) one. Add $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/2^n$ to your list of examples and see how they all compare.

Comment: I beg your pardon for this seemingly silly question, but the elements of the first series also seem very small to me. How do you manage to decide how small is still divergent and how small is small enough to be considered divergent?

Comment: @Sorer You can only develop sound intuition by looking at a range of specific examples.    Looking at examples like $\sum\frac{1}{n^s}$ is a good way to do this; and then things like $\sum\frac{1}{n (\log n)^s}$ etc You'll see how delicate the question is.

Comment: Basic intuition yields that $1/n$ grows smaller slowly than $1/n^2$

Comment: Looking at this page could be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests

Comment: See this [proof](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/harmonic.pdf). Note how the fact that the denominator grows linearly helps us arrive at a contradiction

Comment: It's *not* enough that the terms converge to $0$, it has to happen sufficiently fast, and that is the difference between the two mentioned series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking at it from the wrong way. Instead of looking for intuition into why a series converges or not, try to think about what in your current intuition makes the results you are looking for feel... strange.

In my experience, the most common intuitive thinking people have can be summarized in "Well, I am adding smaller and smaller numbers, so surely, the sum can't just grow beyond all bounds right? *There must be some upper bound to the sum if the summands go to $0$, right*?"

It's that italicized sentence that is usually the crux of the problem. The answer to it is **no**, and while the harmonic series is a very known counterexample, it is not the best in explaining things to our intuition. So, to explain things to our intuitive brain, I would look at two series.

First, we can look at the series

$$\frac12 + \frac12 + \frac13+\frac13+\frac13+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\cdots$$

which *obviously* diverges. Intuition quickly accepts this.

In a similar vein, the series $$\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots$$ *obviously* converges to $1$ because after $n$ steps, the sum is $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$, so intuition also accepts this.

---

At this point, the conclusion that I accepted and live with is:

> I accept, intuitively, that summands converging to $0$ is not a sufficient condition for series convergence. Therefore, it appears that the summands must also converge to $0$ **fast enough**.

I don't really have an intuitive explanation for what "fast enough" means though. The harmonic series is not fast enough, that much I can say for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see now where I was previously wrong. I hope you have a beautiful day.

Comment: Just mentioning that the summands of $\sum 1/n$ and $\sum (-1)^n/n$ converge to zero equally fast ...

Comment: @MartinR True, all I wrote applies to positive sums.

Answer (score 0):

The term of a series must have a $0$ limit for the series to converge. True, but it is only a necessary condition which is by no way sufficient.

What matters (for a monotonic series) is whether the *speed convergence* of the inner term is enough for the sum of remaining terms to have a $0$ limit.

A common way to study the convergence of a series of term $u_n$ ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$) is to considere the auxilliary sequence $\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} u_i$, in fact the sum of all remaining terms. Then the convergence of the series is equivalent to that auxiliary sequence having a $0$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the sequences $n$ and $n^2$ which form the denominators.

How fast does $n$ grow? Every next term is a previous one plus constant number $1$. The crucial part that we add a constant, while $n$ is greater and greater.

What about $n^2$? The next term $(n+1)^2$ is equal to $n^2+(2n+1)$. We add a part of the previous term, which scales with it. The added part is roughly a square root of the previous term, it’s not a constant, it grows as the previous term grows.

This reasoning is quite wavy, but it can help one’s intuition to accept the fact that one series converges, while the other doesn’t.